# How to deploy Spring war file to Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, tomcat

I've been trying to use Maven to transform a RESTful service to a war file and deploy it to Tomcat.
But all I received is a 404 not found.
These are my code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is Greeting.java:

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <start-class>gs-rest-service-master.Application</start-class>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<packaging>war</packaging>
```

The rest service is just fun because I can run it using jar.
But when I move the war file to /webapp and run localhost:8080/rest/greeting,
It failed.Could you help me?
(rest is the name of the rest service,greeting is the function)

Comment: Where is your Controller? What is the Name of the war? How Looks like your web-XML?

Comment: First thing to do would probably be to check the server log file.

Comment: How did u configure the rest service name "rest"? Is is the war file name?

Comment: Are you sure your application got deployed successfully..check tomcat logs

Comment: @localhost999  
I am not sure.I don't know which log to refer to. I check the log today,all I find is start tomcat and shutdown

Comment: @localhost999 <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> ....... <Context path="/rest" docBase="gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war" debug="0" privileged="true" reloadable="true"/> </Host>

Comment: @Jens I have no web.xml in /rest since it's using Spring.

Comment: @mrxy56 Do not deploy the application. Try to run the `Application.java` from your IDE

Comment: @localhost999 It has some mistakes,I can't understand.But the code is downloaded from Spring.io,and the configuration is from Spring.io,I don't think it will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application class is missing few annotations

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And also make sure your pom file has the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Also add  public getters to Greetings class in order to avoid error 406, "Could not find acceptable representation"

```
public class Greeting
{

    private final long   id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public String getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }

}
```

Comment: I change spring-boot-starter-web to spring-boot-starter-tomcat,and add <scope>provided</scope>deliberately.Because I don't want to use built-in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot will make it  build a web application, only when

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

is added. You need to exclude embedded tomcat

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Refer Doc https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications